# Javascript function return number instead of object

Tags: javascript

So, right now, i have some code that looks like this

```
 var citibiz2 = new SLAO_stat(4, 25, 4, 55, SplunktimecitiBiz, "citiBiz2", "citiBiz", '0', 1, subcitiBiz);

 var SLAO_stat = function(SLAhour, SLAmin, SLOhour, SLOmin, Splunktime, statusName, mainArray, number, criticality, location) {
        this.SLAmin = SLAmin;
        this.SLAhour = SLAhour;
        this.SLOmin = SLOmin;
        this.SLOhour = SLOhour;

        //set SLA and SLO time for each function
        var SLAtoday = new Date(time.year, time.month, time.day, SLAhour, SLAmin);
        var SLOtoday = new Date(time.year, time.month, time.day, SLOhour, SLOmin);

        //set SLA and SLO time for the next day
        var SLAtom = addDay(SLAtoday, 1);
        var SLOtom = addDay(SLOtoday, 1);

        //set SLA time for 12 hours before current
        var SLAyest = addDay(SLAtoday, -.5);

        //set SLA and SLO time for the previous day
        var SLOyes = addDay(SLOtoday, -1);
        var SLAyes = addDay(SLAtoday, -1);

        var SLAout;
        var SLOout;


        //if the thing comes in between the time it came in last time and the SLA time tommorow, it's in.
        if (Splunktime > SLAyest && Splunktime < SLAtom) {
            SLAout = SLAtom;
            SLOout = SLOtom;
        } else {
            SLAout = SLAtoday;
            SLOout = SLOtoday;
        }
        //color conditionals

        if//(Splunktime > SLAtoday || currentTime > midyes && Splunktime < midyes && Splunktime > SLAyest && currentTime < SLOtoday){
            (currentTime > SLAtoday && Splunktime > SLAtoday && Splunktime != ""){
            displayColor = 4;
            main_gray++; //gray status
            graydiv = document.getElementById(location);
            document.getElementById(statusName).innerHTML = "<a href='#'><img src='gray.jpg' class = 'select' class = 'image-cropper'></a>";
            if(criticality == 1) $('#gray_container' + number).prepend($(graydiv));
            else $('#gray_container' + number).append($(graydiv));
        }else if (currentTime < SLOout) {
            //green;
            displayColor = 1;
            main_green++;
            document.getElementById(statusName).innerHTML = "<a href='#'><img src='green.png' class = 'select' class = 'image-cropper'></a>";
        } else if (currentTime > SLAout) {
            //red
            displayColor = 2;
            main_red++; //for main status
            document.getElementById(statusName).innerHTML = "<a href='#'><img src='red.png' class = 'select' class = 'image-cropper'></a>";
        } else if (currentTime<SLAout && currentTime>SLOout) {
            //yellow
            displayColor = 3;
            main_yellow++; //for main status
            document.getElementById(statusName).innerHTML = "<a href='#'><img src='yellow.png' class = 'select' class = 'image-cropper'></a>";
        } else {
            //red
            displayColor = 2;
            main_red++; //for main status
            document.getElementById(statusName).innerHTML = "<a href='#'><img src='red.png' class = 'select' class = 'image-cropper'></a>"; 
        }    

        if(mainArray == "citiBiz"){
            if(displayColor == 4) CBrep = 4;
            else if(displayColor == 2 && CBrep < 4)CBrep = 2;
            else if(displayColor == 3 && CBrep < 2)CBrep = 3;
            else if(displayColor == 1 && CBrep < 2)CBrep = 1; 
        }
        else if(mainArray == "creditETL"){
            if(displayColor == 4) CETLrep = 4;
            else if(displayColor == 2 && CETLrep < 4) CETLrep = 2;
            else if(displayColor == 3 && CETLrep < 2) CETLrep = 3;
            else if(displayColor == 1 && CETLrep < 2)CETLrep = 1;
        }
        else alert("There is no array called " + mainArray);
        alert("dc " + displayColor);

        return displayColor; //returns [object Object] instead of a number
    };
```

My code does a series of things to output a number. I would like to return the number instead of an object. Is there a way to do this?

Again, this is a really simplified outline of what is happening in my code. I'm really just asking if it can be done. Thanks!

Comment: You're assigning an object to `number` somewhere in your code that you've not posted.  Return a number from `newfunc`, and you'll have a number rather than an object.

Comment: Okay. You have code that should return a number. It returns an object. You don't know why. How are we supposed to know what's happening? Can I answer "You should type `return 0;` at the beginning of the function"? Without your code, there is no possible way we can make a proper answer.

Comment: My code is 100 lines long in this function, but I'll post it if you really feel like it will help you.

Comment: Debug through it and see what it assigning the `number` value in `// some code`.  It is not assigning it a number.

Comment: I was just asking if it could be done, I don't know why I'm being downvoted.

Comment: See [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Well, while I'm getting downvoted, I might as well post the actual code so that this post won't be all for naught. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're calling the function with the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).  This is constructing a new object.  Depending on the larger context you're working in, you have two options.

**Option 1**

Don't create a new object, and just call the function as a normal function:

```
var citibiz2 = SLAO_stat(4, 25...)
```

**Option 2**

Set the `displayColor` as a property on the object you're creating and use it.  So instead of:

```
return displayColor;
```

You could do:

```
this.displayColor = displayColor;
```

And then access it on the object that's being created by `new`:

```
var citibiz2 = new SLAO_stat(4, 2...)
alert(citibiz2.displayColor); //should be a number
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! I want to appologize for being so new because it lends to stupid mistakes. 
I did not say that this was for a website that is using tomcat. The first method you told me to use actually crashed my site. The second returns undefined.

Comment: The first method definitely changes the behaviour quite drastically - I can understand it making other stuff not work.  The second one shouldn't show `undefined` though - can you double check to ensure the spellings are correct in your code?  You should have the [equivalent of this](http://jsfiddle.net/dhz3eepL/) (more or less).